# Is it possible to use a change the Javascript engine a Cocoa WebView uses?

Tags: cocoa, webview, javascript-engine

I'm working on a html/javascript + cocoa hybrid app. From what I can tell, Cocoa's WebView uses the same javascript engine as Safari (Nitro).

However, there's a couple of things in the V8 JS engine (used by Chrome) that would be nice luxuries to have. Since Chrome and Safari are both Webkit based, I'm wondering wether it's at all possible to change the swap out Nitro for V8 for a cocoa WebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in a cocoa web view... No.
but which a "non-trivial" (ie. huge) amount of engineering you could build your own replacement WebView.

here is the [embedding guide](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html) for v8
and webkit is also open source, and you can get it [here](http://www.webkit.org).

but if you just want it for a couple of convenient aspects of v8, you wouldn't be making good use of your time.

Also google has the [chromium SDK](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/downloads/list) which would be a better starting point that webKit
but still probably not a good use of your time.